# Expanding FULLY a macro as argument

Tags: macros, graphics, expansion

I have a code line that looks like that

```
\includegraphics{\complicatedmacro}
```

The `\complicatedmacro` returns just the name of the picture file, e.g., `mypicture`, so that when I write

```
 \complicatedmacro
```

In my LaTeX code I get the text `mypicture` in the output .pdf

Consequently `\includegraphics{\complicatedmacro}` should just set the picture `mypicture` in the document. But I get an error

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

However when I write `\includegraphics{mypicture}`, everything works fine.

I have the feeling this issue has to do with the expansion process. What is the secret to let the `\complicatedmacro` be fully expanded before the call to `\includegraphics`?

I hope this is enough. I would like a general answer. But if you'd really need the "`\complicatedmacro`", I could write it.

Thanks! :)

> The `\complicatedmacro`'s definition

```
 \newcommand{\usedpicturename}[2]%
    {\ifthenelse{\boolean{shouldusetestpicture}}{#1}{#2}}
```

> Use in the `.tex` file

Now somewhere in the code I set the boolean

```
   \setboolean{shouldusetestpicture}{false}
   \includegraphics{\usedpicturename{mypicturetest}{mypicturecool}} %Here pops up the error
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the definition of `\complicatedmacro`.

Comment: Ok. Here we go! :)

Comment: if `\complicatedmacro` expanded to `mypicture` as stated you would not get that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ifthenelse` does not work by expansion, it involves assignments so you can not "expand this fully". There are plenty of conditional macros that do work via expansion, such as

```
\newcommand{\usedpicturename}[2]%
    {\ifshouldusetestpicture #1\else #2\fi}
```

Comment: I'm glad and honoured that the author of the ``ifthen`` package answer my question so speedily :), but on the other hand I feel so stupid that I searched a solution for this problem for soooo long (``\expand``, ``\edef``, ``\noexpand``, ``\tracingmacros``... ) And the answer is so simple! :-S Thanks and blessings, David.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus note the question (and answer) are only related to ifthen (which you didn't mention at all in the question initially) and not to `\includegraphics` (for example try `\typeout{\usedpicturename{a}{b}}`) questions should _always_ have a reproducible test case.

Comment: "Thought you might answer this one:-) "

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes touché :-)